# How to multiply many columns in a folder in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-science

I have a CSV folder with many files. Each csv file looks like this I would like to take each column in csv file in a folder to be multiplied by 2x?

***csv 1

```
   Name   Sales
   0 Sam    250
   0 Steve  500
   0 Ann    600




csv 2***


 Name   Sales
 0 Sam    250
 0 Steve  300
 0 Ann    400
```

Looking to have this

```
csv 1

   Name   Sales
   0 Sam    500
   0 Steve  1000
   0 Ann    1200

csv 2***


 Name   Sales
 0 Sam    500
 0 Steve  600
 0 Ann    800
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
df_paths = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv'] 
df_lst = [pd.read_csv(_) for _ in df_paths]

for df in df_lst:
    df['Sales']*=2
```

Note that the `df['Sales']*=2` line effects the original DataFrames and not copies of them. They should be updated in each DataFrame of df_lst.

Answer (score 0):

this will helpful !

```
basepath="<folder path>"
files = list(filter(lambda x: '.csv' in x, os.listdir(basepath)))
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f"{basepath}/{file}")
    df_ = df.drop(["Name"])
    cols = df_.columns
    df_[cols] =df_[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
    df_ = df_.multiply(2)
    dfnew = pd.concat(df[df["Name"]],df_,axis=1)
    dfnew.to_csv(f"{file}_n.csv")
```